# How to authenticate azure functions with firebase auth

Tags: c#, firebase-authentication, azure-functions

Before I explain my problem I want to share some insights about what I am trying to do. I am developing a serverless application in Azure. My azure app service plan contains multiple azure function application and each function app contains multiple azure functions(HTTP triggers/API) in it. Now I want to authenticate all the serverless API. I am using firebase to authenticate my users. How I can achieve it in a minimal and reusable manner.

I already use firebase in asp.net core for authentication in a monolithic manner but for a situation like this, I am not sure How to do.

In a Monolithic manner. In our ConfigureServices method, we need to register the services necessary to handle authentication and to specify the parameters of our Firebase project.

```
services
.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/my-firebase-project";
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/my-firebase-project",
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = "my-firebase-project",
        ValidateLifetime = true
    };
});
```

Then in our Configure method, we have to do one simple call to register the actual middleware that will handle the authentication.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Comment: Have you tried the dependency injection feature of Functions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

Comment: you need to share with us your architectural design. are you planning to have 1 gateway service that will then provide the bearer auth to the rest of the services? are you exposing publicly all of your APIs? do you need an example of how to perform bearer authentication?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Yes, we are planing to use azure api management gateway service.  and yes I need an example of how to perform bearer authentication which is firebase auth in my case.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/z70vyctR

Comment: have you ever achieved this? i am looking for example same solution as I am trying to migrate from .net core api to azure functions but i couldnt figure out how to set up that middleware authentication.

Comment: @Emil no I am not able to achieve this.

Comment: @MalikKashmiri after some research found out that it is not supported by Azure yet. too unfortunate :(